# Check the next line while read current line using streamreader

Tags: c#

This is the content of my file:

---

```
atul,salunke
amol,salunke
anil,salunke
;dandegaon
amar,salunke
;bhoom
akash,salunke
;chennai
pappu,salunke
```

---

This is my code.  I am missing the comment `;chennai` while flushing bulk after count 5.  That is why I need to check the next line's content while reading the current line.

This is my code:

```
int counter = 0;
int cnt = 0;
string line = "";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=atul-pc;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True");
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock
                                       | SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers
                                       | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction, null);
con.Open();
bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5;
bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 3000;

string[] sField = null;
DataRow row;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("H:\\sample file.txt");

DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("iID"); table.Columns.Add("iID", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("vchFirstName"); table.Columns.Add("vchFirstName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn("vchLastName"); table.Columns.Add("vchLastName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
DataColumn col4 = new DataColumn("Comment"); table.Columns.Add("Comment", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "userDetails";
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("iID", "iID");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("vchFirstName", "vchFirstName");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("vchLastName", "vchLastName");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Comment", "Comment");
int priv = 0;
 while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     int columnCount =0 ;
    char[] cDelim = new char[] { ',' };
    sField = line.Split(cDelim);
    if (line.Contains(","))
    {
        counter++;
        priv = counter;
        row = table.NewRow();
        row["iID"] = counter;
        foreach (string s in sField)
        {
            columnCount++;
            row[columnCount] = s.Trim();
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);

    }
    if (line.Contains(";"))
    {

        DataRow[] result = table.Select("iID="+priv+"");
        result[0]["Comment"] = line.Trim();

    }

    if (Math.Floor((double)counter / 5) != Math.Floor((double)(counter - 1) / 5))
    {
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);// here i missing coment  ;chennai
        table.Clear();
    }
    cnt++;
}
```

Comment: sorry ,You need an IDE that supports indentation.

Comment: Try putting your streamreader in a using statement

Comment: The text area has formatting available. Post your code, select it all, and then press Ctrl+K (or click the toolbar button that looks like `{}`). For help, click the orange button with the `?` on it that appears above the top right corner of the text area. :-) You can preview your question in a WYSIWYG fashion right below the text area where you're typing it, so you can make any adjustments before submitting it. You can also always [edit] your own question to fix anything that doesn't look right after posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having trouble following you, but I think the problem is that you are calling `table.Clear()` after the `bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table)`. You should call `table.Rows.Clear()`. Calling `Table.Clear()` dumps everything from the table, including the columns. It looks like you mean to dump just the rows.

While you're at it, you can also makes several changes that will help you out...

- use `File.ReadAllLines()`
- use a `ForEach` to loop.
- Trim your strings as you select them.
- Use `string.Format()`

something like this:

```
int priv = 0;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("H:\\sample file.txt").Select(s=>s.Trim());
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains(";"))
    {
        DataRow[] result = table.Select(string.Format("iID={0}", priv));
        result[0]["Comment"] = line;
    }
    else
    {
        row = table.NewRow();
        row["iID"] = counter;
        counter++;
        priv = counter;
        var words = line
            .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(it => it.Trim());
        int columnCount = 0;
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            columnCount++;
            row[columnCount] = word;
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    if (Math.Floor((double)counter / 5) != Math.Floor((double)(counter - 1) / 5))
    {
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);// here i missing coment  ;chennai
        table.Clear();
    }

    cnt++;
}
```